# Download/Retrieve existing Elastic Beanstalk environment configuration

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I have setup an elastic beanstalk application and environment using the AWS Web Console. Everything works well and as needed. Now we would like grab all the configuration for this environment so that we can setup this environment again, possibly using EB CLI for maintenance and deployment purposes (we are looking to transition to a different AWS account and clone it over there). I tried the `eb config get` using the EB CLI but I get the error
`git:(master) ✗ eb config get our-env-test  ERROR: Elastic Beanstalk could not find any saved configuration with the name "our-env-test".`

Comment: Are you sure you have IAM permissions to do that? Are you providing the right AWS creds during the call? Test with `eb config list`

Comment: @MarkYoung yes. I just realized that when I do `eb config list` I get the config name and I should be using the returned config name with `eg config get` and not the environment name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I should be using the config name returned by the command `eb config list` and not the environment name. For example, in my case the environment name was `our-env-test`. So when I run the command `eb config list` I get back `our-env-test-config`. Now when I run the command `eb config get our-env-test-config`

```
>> eb config get our-env-test-config
    Configuration saved at: /Users/me/our-env/.elasticbeanstalk/saved_configs/our-env-test-config.cfg.yml
```

The resulting config file is stored in the `.elasticbeanstalk` directory
NOTE: Even before all this you need to initialize the directory with the appropriate EB project by running `eb init` command

Answer (score 0):

Use `eb config -d <environment_name>`.

The `-d` flag displays the current environment configuration settings.